# No such file or directory when trying to save file

Tags: android, file, directory, save

For an App I am developing, I want to write some text to a text file on the SD card. I've tried to do that with the code below. This gives an error but I can't see why. As far as I can tell I have followed all the examples on the web perfectly. In logcat I see the first log, but not the second one so the problem is in the creation of the file. Do you guys have an idea what's going wrong?

```
public void saveDataToFile(String data, String fileName) {

    Log.d("Checks", "Trying to save data");

    try {
        // Set up the file directory
        String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Data Folder";
        File fileDirectory = new File(filePath);
        fileDirectory.mkdirs();
        Log.d("Checks", "Directory created");

        // Set up the file itself
        File textFile = new File(fileDirectory, fileName);
        textFile.createNewFile();
        Log.d("Checks", "File created");

        // Write to the file
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(textFile);
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream);
        outputStreamWriter.append(data);
        outputStreamWriter.close();
        fileOutputStream.close();

        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Done writing to SD card", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

**EDIT**:

Turns out I had forgotten to add the right permission to the manifest. It works now!

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Are you testing in emulator?

Comment: Did you declare the proper uses permissions to access and write to the External SD card ?

Comment: Well I feel silly! I forgot to set the permission in the manifest :) .

Answer (score 2):

Did you declare the proper uses permissions to access and write to the External SD card ?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```